# Error parsing query from C# program to SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, parsing, sql-server-ce, parsing-error

I need to update the details in a certain row of my SQL Server CE database as the user wants requires to. But I get an error

> There was an error parsing the query.[Token line number=1,Token line offset=31,Token in error=Name]

My query is:

```
"Update MembersTable set First Name='" + txtFirstName.Text +
    "', Surname='" + txtSurname.Text + 
    "', Middle Name='" + txtMiddleName.Text +
    "',Home Address='" + txtAddress.Text +
    "',Date Of Birth='" + dtpDOB.Text + 
    "',Home Phone No='" + txtHomePhone.Text +
    "',Mobile No='" + txtMobilePhone.Text + 
    "',Email='" + txtEmail.Text +
    "',Profession='" + txtProfession.Text + 
    "',Cell Leaders Name='" + txtCellLeader.Text +
    "' Where ID='" + DC.ID + "'";"
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like your column names contain spaces.
To deal with this, you'd want to enclose the column name with square brackets `[ ]`

```cs
"Update MembersTable set [First Name]='" + txtFirstName.Text + "',Surname='" + txtSurname.Text + "',[Middle Name]='" // ...
```